# changing Material-ui table style in row.getRowProps()

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-table, react-table-v7

In my react application I'm using Material-UI enhanced table which is based on react-table and I would like to change the style of their rows.

Reading from documentation (https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/) in the component TableRow should be used the prop "classes" to change the style, but in the MaterialUi code props are read this way:

```
  <TableRow {...row.getRowProps()}>
```

My question is how can I use the prop classes if the TableRow props are added automatically? I thought I needed to have this:

```
 <TableRow classes="rowStyle ">
```

where rowStyle is:

```
 const styles = {
       rowStyle : {
          padding: 10,
          border: "1px solid red"
       }
    };
```

But obviously I can't this way, how can I add "classes" to the getRowProps() and the new style in it?

I couldn't find an explanation or a good example in official documentation or stackOverflow

Many thanks for the help

EnhancedTable.js:

```js
import React from "react";

import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import MaUTable from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableFooter from "@material-ui/core/TableFooter";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
import TablePaginationActions from "./TablePaginationActions";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
import TableToolbar from "./TableToolbar";
import {
  useGlobalFilter,
  usePagination,
  useRowSelect,
  useSortBy,
  useTable,
} from "react-table";

const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
  ({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
    const defaultRef = React.useRef();
    const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

    React.useEffect(() => {
      resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
    }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);

    return (
      <div>
        <Checkbox ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
      </div>
    );
  }
);

const inputStyle = {
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0,
  border: 0,
  background: "transparent",
};

// Create an editable cell renderer
const EditableCell = ({
  value: initialValue,
  row: { index },
  column: { id },
  updateMyData, // This is a custom function that we supplied to our table instance
}) => {
  // We need to keep and update the state of the cell normally
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  // We'll only update the external data when the input is blurred
  const onBlur = () => {
    updateMyData(index, id, value);
  };

  // If the initialValue is changed externall, sync it up with our state
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  return (
    <input
      style={inputStyle}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      onBlur={onBlur}
    />
  );
};

EditableCell.propTypes = {
  cell: PropTypes.shape({
    value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  }),
  row: PropTypes.shape({
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  }),
  column: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  }),
  updateMyData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

// Set our editable cell renderer as the default Cell renderer
const defaultColumn = {
  Cell: EditableCell,
};

const EnhancedTable = ({
  columns,
  data,
  setData,
  updateMyData,
  skipPageReset,
}) => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page,
    gotoPage,
    setPageSize,
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    setGlobalFilter,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize, selectedRowIds, globalFilter },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      defaultColumn,
      autoResetPage: !skipPageReset,
      // updateMyData isn't part of the API, but
      // anything we put into these options will
      // automatically be available on the instance.
      // That way we can call this function from our
      // cell renderer!
      updateMyData,
    },
    useGlobalFilter,
    useSortBy,
    usePagination,
    useRowSelect,
    (hooks) => {
      hooks.allColumns.push((columns) => [
        // Let's make a column for selection
        {
          id: "selection",
          // The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
          // to render a checkbox.  Pagination is a problem since this will select all
          // rows even though not all rows are on the current page.  The solution should
          // be server side pagination.  For one, the clients should not download all
          // rows in most cases.  The client should only download data for the current page.
          // In that case, getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps works fine.
          Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
          // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
          // to the render a checkbox
          Cell: ({ row }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
        },
        ...columns,
      ]);
    }
  );

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    gotoPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setPageSize(Number(event.target.value));
  };

  const removeByIndexs = (array, indexs) =>
    array.filter((_, i) => !indexs.includes(i));

  const deleteUserHandler = (event) => {
    const newData = removeByIndexs(
      data,
      Object.keys(selectedRowIds).map((x) => parseInt(x, 10))
    );
    setData(newData);
  };

  const addUserHandler = (user) => {
    const newData = data.concat([user]);
    setData(newData);
  };

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <TableToolbar
        numSelected={Object.keys(selectedRowIds).length}
        deleteUserHandler={deleteUserHandler}
        addUserHandler={addUserHandler}
        preGlobalFilteredRows={preGlobalFilteredRows}
        setGlobalFilter={setGlobalFilter}
        globalFilter={globalFilter}
      />
      <MaUTable {...getTableProps()}>
        <TableHead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                  {...(column.id === "selection"
                    ? column.getHeaderProps()
                    : column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps()))}
                >
                  {column.render("Header")}
                  {column.id !== "selection" ? (
                    <TableSortLabel
                      active={column.isSorted}
                      // react-table has a unsorted state which is not treated here
                      direction={column.isSortedDesc ? "desc" : "asc"}
                    />
                  ) : null}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <TableRow {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <TableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                      {cell.render("Cell")}
                    </TableCell>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>

        <TableFooter>
          <TableRow>
            <TablePagination
              rowsPerPageOptions={[
                5,
                10,
                25,
                { label: "All", value: data.length },
              ]}
              colSpan={3}
              count={data.length}
              rowsPerPage={pageSize}
              page={pageIndex}
              SelectProps={{
                inputProps: { "aria-label": "rows per page" },
                native: true,
              }}
              onChangePage={handleChangePage}
              onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
              ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActions}
            />
          </TableRow>
        </TableFooter>
      </MaUTable>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

EnhancedTable.propTypes = {
  columns: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  updateMyData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  skipPageReset: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

export default EnhancedTable;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but i think the first step to your solution is the correct definition of styles for the material-ui element. I can't say for certain if there is another way to generate these styles, but a simple object such as:
`const inputStyle = { padding: 0, margin: 0, border: 0, background: "transparent", };`
will probably not work. You probably have to use the material styles for that.

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    border: "1px solid red",
    padding: 10
  },
});
```

and then you have to use the style hook in the component definition:

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

When overriding a material-ui definition this part is the important one to define which part is going to overriden (not allowed to include pictures yet, sorry):
[Material-Ui CSS keys for Table Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtOAt.png)

Then you can override the style `<TableRow classes={{ root: classes.root }}>` or in your case maybe more like `<TableRow classes={{ root: classes.root }} {...row.getRowProps()}>`

An additional problem you might face is that you have to override the style of the TableCells too, because the overlap the TableRow border.
I have here a code sandbox that is by no means perfect, but should help you on the right track: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-535zq?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 2):

```
import {  makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  rowStyle : {
       padding: 10,
       border: "1px solid red"
  }
}));


const EnhancedTable = ()=>{

    const classes = useStyles();

    return(
        <TableRow className={classes.rowStyle}/>
    )

}
```